# why the import/export from app.js to routes.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function in my app.js that I would like to use in my routes.js file, but the export is not working properly.

app.js:

```
module.exports = function extractquestions(){
     extractq();
};
```

routes.js:

```
let extractquestions = require('../app.js');
```

the error I get :

```
TypeError: extractquestions is not a function
```

Comment: The function `extractquestions` calls itself recursively, ad infinitum. What purpose does that serve?

Answer (score 1):

The other guy is right.
But you also do like this:

app.js:

```
function print(x){
    console.log(x);
}

module.exports = function printSenctence(sentence) {
    print(sentence);
}
```

and route.js:

```
const printSenctence = require('./app');
  
printSenctence("Everything is awesome!!");
```

Hope I help ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export function, try this:

helper.js

```
function add(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = {
  add
};
```

main.js

```
const { add } = require('./helper.js');
console.log(add(2,3));
```